# WiFi apps not working when VPN apps are connected

Tags: wi-fi, windows, internet, vpn, remote-access

I have decided to use the AirMore app to connect my Android phone to my Windows computer. My internet speed was very slow, so I decided to connect to AirMore using WiFi. It was very good with very high speed and very high quality. But when my VPN app is connected, it's not working.

Also, I have tested scrcpy and it's not working either.

Is it possible to use these types of apps when the VPN is connected?

Comment: That depends on the VPN and the sharing app. Some VPN allow accessing the local network while connected to the VPN, others not. Even if VPN allows local access DNS will be different which may confuse the sharing app.